# Ubuntu SFTP no longer works after server reboot

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ftp, sftp

I was setting my entire LAMP server on ubuntu server 20.04 with guides from this site: https://devanswers.co/

Finally I managed to make everything work, including sftp based on https://devanswers.co/configure-sftp-web-server-document-root/

Unfortunately while trying to setup multiple virtual hosts I forgot to set ownership of new directories. While trying to fix permission errors I was trying to redo many steps from the guides. Finally I realized that I should add ovnership and for a while everything worked. But after I reboot server, I can no longer connect to sftp. Filezilla returns `FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort`, and notepad++ returns this:

```
Connecting
[SFTP] Host key accepted
[SFTP] Successfully authenticated
[SFTP] Error initialising channel: Socket error: Unknown error 
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

What did happen? I'm almost sure that I messed up something, since i'm new with ubuntu. But I don't know what I did since I changed a lot of thing in the meantime, trying to redo all the steps from linked guides while I was unaware that I should change directories ovnership.

If I should provide more logs, than please guide me - where can I find those? Since N++ did get authenticated, than server deffinetly does have some logs that could help find the reason of my problems, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with directories chmod and chown. It's hard to tell me right now if the reboot caused this, or if it was my ingeration that caused this. Anyway, I found help here: https://devanswers.co/configure-sftp-web-server-document-root/